# App-Scripts- How to unprotect series of repeated ranges at once?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to protect my whole sheet but just want some ranges unprotected, the ranges are in repeated progression series. So I don't want to create a new range and add it to the unprotected. Is there any shorter method. Just give you guys a broad picture I have dynamic sheet with 40 rows and "n" number of columns. but I want starting from Col3 C5:F35 unprotected then skip 4 columns completely then again K5:N35 unprotected and so on till lastCol. I have huge number of columns so doing this manually is next to impossible. Help on this matter would be highly appreciated. I have attached a picture which might help clearing up some confusions.

[spreadsheet screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93slH.png)

Comment: A better explanation and perhaps some spreadsheet screen shots might be of some value.  Integrate some images into your explanation.

Comment: I have just attached a screenshot.Thanks.

Comment: I think you may need to use a rangelist: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getActiveRangeList()

Comment: hmm might work..The difficult part is to skip columns or iterate the rangeList :(

Comment: RangeList is a class with methods: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a Google Script and, instead of it protecting ranges, have it protect ranges like the following:

```js
function protectColumns() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let spreadsheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  let lastColumn = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();
  let lastRow = spreadsheet.getLastColumn();

  let range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 2); // Sets the range from Row 1 Column1 to Last Row Column 2
  let protection = range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');

  for(let i=7; i<lastColumn; i+=8) { //Starting at column 7, Protect 4 rows, skip 4 rows, repeat
    range = spreadsheet.getRange(1, i, lastRow, 4);
    range.protect().setDescription('Sample protected range');
  }
}
```

This should do what I think you want. It protects the first 2 rows, skips the next 4, protects the next 4, and repeats. I would only caution it may miss protecting the last section of columns. Let me know if there are any issues.